# Grouping nearest locations in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, geolocation, aggregation-framework, aggregate, geonear

Location point saved as

```
{
  "location_point" : {
  "coordinates" : [ 
      -95.712891, 
      37.09024
  ],
  "type" : "Point"
  },
  "location_point" : {
  "coordinates" : [ 
      -95.712893, 
      37.09024
  ],
  "type" : "Point"
  },
  "location_point" : {
  "coordinates" : [ 
      -85.712883, 
      37.09024
  ],
  "type" : "Point"
  },
  .......
  .......
}
```

There are several documents. I need to `group` it by nearest locations.
After grouping first econd locations will be in one document and third one in the second. 
Please not that location point of first and second is not equal. Both are nearest places.

Is there any way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you think "group by nearest" actually means? Show an example of some documents and what you would expect as output to a query. One document really does not tell us, other than it's probably the nearest and therefore the result. Show any attempted code as well, as at the very least it might give some more indication as to what you are actually asking.

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: Still more than just a little vague. When I said to demonstrate what you actually mean then an expected result from the supplied documents would at least give some idea of what you expect. Perhaps you mean "groups" of "within 5 kilometers", and "between 5 to 10 kilometers", and so on up to "over 100km". But without showing an actual expectation "group by nearest" really does not tell us anything. You could be and really "should be" a lot more descriptive.

Comment: Yes. You said it. Like "groups" of "within 5 kilometers;

Comment: What is the use of giving a default coordinates in $geoNear ?

Comment: Actual need is, When loading the site, a map is displayed. In map, there is a count of users located at that place.Ex: In America 5 , Russia 18 .... When zooming the map the it spread as single users location

Answer (score 7):

The quick and lazy explanation is to use both [`$geoNear`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/) and [`$bucket`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/bucket/) aggregation pipeline stages to get the result:

```
.aggregate([
    {
      "$geoNear": {
        "near": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [
            -95.712891,
            37.09024
          ]
        },
        "spherical": true,
        "distanceField": "distance",
        "distanceMultiplier": 0.001
      }
    },
    {
      "$bucket": {
        "groupBy": "$distance",
        "boundaries": [
          0, 5, 10, 20,  50,  100,  500
        ],
        "default": "greater than 500km",
        "output": {
          "count": {
            "$sum": 1
          },
          "docs": {
            "$push": "$$ROOT"
          }
        }
      }
    }
])
```

The longer form is that you should probably understand the *"why?"* part of how this solves the problem, and optionally even understand that even though this does apply at least one aggregation operator only introduced in recent MongoDB versions, this actually has all been possible right back to MongoDB 2.4.

## Using $geoNear

The main thing to look for in any "grouping" is basically going to be a `"distance"` field added to a result of a "near" query indicating how far that result is from the coordinates used in the search. Fortunately this is exactly what the [`$geoNear`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/) aggregation pipeline stage does.

The basic stage would be something like this:

```
{
  "$geoNear": {
    "near": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
        -95.712891,
        37.09024
      ]
    },
    "spherical": true,
    "distanceField": "distance",
    "distanceMultiplier": 0.001
  }
},
```

This stage has three *mandatory* arguments that must be supplied:

- **near** - Is the location to use for the query. This can either be in legacy coordinate pair form or as GeoJSON data. Anything as GeoJSON is basically considered in **meters** for results, since that is the GeoJSON standard.
- **spherical** - *Mandatory*, but really only when the index type is `2dsphere`. It defaults to `false`, but you probably do want a `2dsphere` index for any real Geolocation data on the surface of the earth.
- **distanceField** - This is also always required and it is the name of the field to be added to the document which will contain the distance from the queried location via `near`. This result will be in either radians or meters depending on the type of the data format used in the `near` argument. The result is also affected by the *optional* argument as noted next.

The optional argument is:

- **distanceMultiplier** - This alters the result in the named field path to `distanceField`. The *multiplier* is applied to the returned value and can be used for *"conversion"* of units to the desired format.

  > **NOTE:** The `distanceMultiplier` does **NOT** apply to other optional arguments like `maxDistance` or `minDistance`. Constraints applied to these optional arguments **must be in the original returned units format**. Therefore with GeoJSON any bounds set for "min" or "max" distances need to be calculated as **meters** regardless of whether you converted a `distanceMultiplier` value with something like `km` or `miles`.

The main thing this is going to do is simply return the "nearest" documents ( up to 100 by default ) in *order* of nearest to furthest away and include the field named as the `distanceField` within the existing document contents and that's what was mentioned earlier as the actual output which will allow you to "group".

The `distanceMultiplier` here is simply converting the default **meters** of GeoJSON to **kilometers** for output. If you wanted **miles** in the output then you would change the multiplier. i.e:

```
"distanceMultiplier": 0.000621371
```

It's totally optional, but you will need to be aware of what units ( converted or not ) are to be applied in the next *"grouping"* stage:

---

The actual *"grouping"* comes down to three different options depending on your available MongoDB and you actual needs:

### Option 1 - $bucket

The [`$bucket`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/bucket/) pipeline stage was added with MongoDB 3.4. It's actually one of a few *"pipeline stages"* which were added in that version which are really more like a *macro function* or a basic form of *shorthand* for writing a combination of pipeline stages and actual operators. More on that later.

The main basic arguments are the `groupBy` expression, the `boundaries` which specifies the ***lower*** bounds for "grouping" ranges, and a `default` option which is basically applied as the *"grouping key" or `_id` field in output whenever data matching the `groupBy` expression does not fall between the entries defined with the `boundaries`.

```
    {
      "$bucket": {
        "groupBy": "$distance",
        "boundaries": [
          0, 5, 10, 20,  50,  100,  500
        ],
        "default": "greater than 500km",
        "output": {
          "count": {
            "$sum": 1
          },
          "docs": {
            "$push": "$$ROOT"
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

The other section is the `output`, which basically contains the same accumulator expressions that you would use with a [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/), and that really should give you an indication of which aggregation pipeline stage this [`$bucket`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/bucket/) actually expands to. Those do the actual "data collection" per "grouping key".

Whilst useful, there is one small fault with [`$bucket`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/bucket/) in that the `_id` output will only ever be the values defined within the `boundaries` or within the `default` option where data falls outside of the `boundaries` constraint. If you wanted something *"nicer"*, it would be typically be done in client post processing of the results, with something like:

```
result = result
  .map(({ _id, ...e }) =>
    ({
      _id: (!isNaN(parseFloat(_id)) && isFinite(_id))
        ? `less than ${bounds[bounds.indexOf(_id)+1]}km`
        : _id,
      ...e
    })
  );
```

That would replace any *plain numeric* values within the returned `_id` fields with a more meaningful "string" describing what is actually being grouped.

Note that whilst a `default` is *"optional"*, you will receive a hard error in the case where any data falls outside of the boundary range. In fact the very specific error returned leads us to the next case.

## Option 2 - $group and $switch

From what was said above you might have realized that the *"macro translation"* from the [`$bucket`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/bucket/) pipeline stage actually becomes a [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stage, and one that specifically applies the [`$switch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/switch/) operator as it's argument to the `_id` field for grouping. Again the [`$switch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/switch/) operator was introduced with MongoDB 3.4.

Essentially this is really a *manual* construction of what was shown above using [`$bucket`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/bucket/), with a little fine tuning on the output of the `_id` fields and being a little less *terse* with the expressions that are produced by the former. In fact you can use the "explain" output of an aggregation pipeline to see something *"similar"* to the following listing, but using the defined pipeline stage above:

```
{
  "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "$switch": {
        "branches": [
          {
            "case": {
              "$and": [
                {
                  "$lt": [
                    "$distance",
                    5
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "$gte": [
                    "$distance",
                    0
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            "then": "less than 5km"
          },
          {
            "case": {
              "$and": [
                {
                  "$lt": [
                    "$distance",
                    10
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            "then": "less than 10km"
          },
          {
            "case": {
              "$and": [
                {
                  "$lt": [
                    "$distance",
                    20
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            "then": "less than 20km"
          },
          {
            "case": {
              "$and": [
                {
                  "$lt": [
                    "$distance",
                    50
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            "then": "less than 50km"
          },
          {
            "case": {
              "$and": [
                {
                  "$lt": [
                    "$distance",
                    100
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            "then": "less than 100km"
          },
          {
            "case": {
              "$and": [
                {
                  "$lt": [
                    "$distance",
                    500
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            "then": "less than 500km"
          }
        ],
        "default": "greater than 500km"
      }
    },
    "count": {
      "$sum": 1
    },
    "docs": {
      "$push": "$$ROOT"
    }
  }
}
```

In fact aside from the clearer *"labelling"* the only actual difference is the [`$bucket`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/bucket/) uses the [`$gte`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/gte/) expression along with an [`$lte`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lte/) on every single `case`. This is not necessary due to how [`$switch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/switch/) actually works and how the logical conditions *"fall through"* just like they would in the common language counterpart usage of a `switch` logic block.

This is really more about a matter of *personal preference* to whether you are happier defining the output "strings" for the `_id` within the `case` statements or if you are okay with post processing values in order to reformat things like that.

Either way, these basically return the same output ( except there is a defined *order* to `$bucket` results ) as does our third option.

## Option 3 - $group and $cond

As noted all the above is essentially based around the [`$switch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/switch/) operator, but just like it's counterpart in various programming language implementations a "switch statement" is really just a cleaner and more convenient way of writing `if .. then .. else if ...` and so on. MongoDB also has a `if .. then .. else` expression right back to MongoDB 2.2 with [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/):

```
{
  "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "$cond": [
        {
          "$and": [
            {
              "$lt": [
                "$distance",
                5
              ]
            },
            {
              "$gte": [
                "$distance",
                0
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        "less then 5km",
        {
          "$cond": [
            {
              "$and": [
                {
                  "$lt": [
                    "$distance",
                    10
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            "less then 10km",
            {
              "$cond": [
                {
                  "$and": [
                    {
                      "$lt": [
                        "$distance",
                        20
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                },
                "less then 20km",
                {
                  "$cond": [
                    {
                      "$and": [
                        {
                          "$lt": [
                            "$distance",
                            50
                          ]
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    "less then 50km",
                    {
                      "$cond": [
                        {
                          "$and": [
                            {
                              "$lt": [
                                "$distance",
                                100
                              ]
                            }
                          ]
                        },
                        "less then 100km",
                        "greater than 500km"
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "count": {
      "$sum": 1
    },
    "docs": {
      "$push": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "location_point": "$location_point",
        "distance": "$distance"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Again it's really all just the same, with the main difference being that instead of a "clean array" of options to process as "cases", what you have instead is a nested set of conditions where the `else` just contains another [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/), right up until the end of the "boundaries" are found and then the `else` contains just the `default` value.

Since we are also at least *"pretending"* that we are going back as far as MongoDB 2.4 ( which is the constraint for actually running with [`$geoNear`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/), then other things like `$$ROOT` would not be available in that version so instead you would simply name all the field expressions of the document in order to add that content with a [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/).

---

## Code Generation

All of this really should come down to that the "grouping" is actually done with the [`$bucket`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/bucket/) and that it's probably what you would use unless you wanted some customization of the output or if your MongoDB version did not support it ( though you probably should not be running any MongoDB under 3.4 at this present time of writing ).

Of course any other form is longer in the required syntax, but really just the same array of arguments can be applied to essentially generate and run either of the shown forms above.

An example listing ( for NodeJS ) follows which demonstrates that it's really just a simple process to generate everything here from just a simple array of `bounds` for the grouping, and even just a few defined options which can both be re-used within pipeline operations as well as any client pre or post processing for either generation of the pipeline instructions, or for manipulation of the returned results into a *"prettier"* output format.

```
const { Schema } = mongoose = require('mongoose');

const uri = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test',
      options = { useNewUrlParser: true };

mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);
mongoose.set('debug', true);

const geoSchema = new Schema({
  location_point: {
    type: { type: String, enum: ["Point"], default: "Point" },
    coordinates: [Number, Number]
  }
});

geoSchema.index({ "location_point": "2dsphere" },{ background: false });

const GeoModel = mongoose.model('GeoModel', geoSchema, 'geojunk');

const [{ location_point: near }] = data = [
  [ -95.712891, 37.09024 ],
  [ -95.712893, 37.09024 ],
  [ -85.712883, 37.09024 ]
].map(coordinates => ({ location_point: { type: 'Point', coordinates } }));


const log = data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2));

(async function() {

  try {
    const conn = await mongoose.connect(uri, options);

    // Clean data
    await Promise.all(
      Object.entries(conn.models).map(([k,m]) => m.deleteMany())
    );

    // Insert data
    await GeoModel.insertMany(data);

    const bounds = [ 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 500 ];
    const distanceField = "distance";


    // Run three sample cases
    for ( let test of [0,1,2] ) {

      let pipeline = [
        { "$geoNear": {
          near,
          "spherical": true,
          distanceField,
          "distanceMultiplier": 0.001
        }},
        (() => {

          // Standard accumulators
          const output = {
            "count":  { "$sum": 1 },
            "docs": { "$push": "$$ROOT" }
          };

          switch (test) {

            case 0:
              log("Using $bucket");
              return (
                { "$bucket": {
                  "groupBy": `$${distanceField}`,
                  "boundaries": [ 0, ...bounds ],
                  "default": `greater than ${[...bounds].pop()}km`,
                  output
                }}
              );
            case  1:
              log("Manually using $switch");
              let branches = bounds.map((bound,i) =>
                ({
                  'case': {
                    '$and': [
                      { '$lt': [ `$${distanceField}`, bound ] },
                      ...((i === 0) ? [{ '$gte': [ `$${distanceField}`, 0 ] }]: [])
                    ]
                  },
                  'then': `less than ${bound}km`
                })
              );
              return (
                { "$group": {
                  "_id": {
                    "$switch": {
                      branches,
                      "default": `greater than ${[...bounds].pop()}km`
                    }
                  },
                  ...output
                }}
              );
            case 2:
              log("Legacy using $cond");
              let _id = null;

              for (let i = bounds.length -1; i > 0; i--) {
                let rec = {
                  '$cond': [
                    { '$and': [
                      { '$lt': [ `$${distanceField}`, bounds[i-1] ] },
                      ...((i == 1) ? [{ '$gte': [ `$${distanceField}`, 0 ] }] : [])
                    ]},
                    `less then ${bounds[i-1]}km`
                  ]
                };

                if ( _id == null ) {
                  rec['$cond'].push(`greater than ${bounds[i]}km`);
                } else {
                  rec['$cond'].push( _id );
                }
                _id = rec;
              }

              // Older MongoDB may require each field instead of $$ROOT
              output.docs.$push =
                ["_id", "location_point", distanceField]
                  .reduce((o,e) => ({ ...o, [e]: `$${e}` }),{});
              return ({ "$group": { _id, ...output } });

          }

        })()
      ];

      let result = await GeoModel.aggregate(pipeline);


      // Text based _id for test: 0 with $bucket
      if ( test === 0 )
        result = result
          .map(({ _id, ...e }) =>
            ({
              _id: (!isNaN(parseFloat(_id)) && isFinite(_id))
                ? `less than ${bounds[bounds.indexOf(_id)+1]}km`
                : _id,
              ...e
            })
          );

      log({ pipeline, result });

    }

  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
  } finally {
    mongoose.disconnect();
  }

})()
```

And sample output ( and of course ALL listings above are generated from this code ):

```
Mongoose: geojunk.createIndex({ location_point: '2dsphere' }, { background: false })
"Using $bucket"
{
  "result": [
    {
      "_id": "less than 5km",
      "count": 2,
      "docs": [
        {
          "_id": "5ca897dd2efdc41b79d5fe94",
          "location_point": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
              -95.712891,
              37.09024
            ]
          },
          "__v": 0,
          "distance": 0
        },
        {
          "_id": "5ca897dd2efdc41b79d5fe95",
          "location_point": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
              -95.712893,
              37.09024
            ]
          },
          "__v": 0,
          "distance": 0.00017759511720976155
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": "greater than 500km",
      "count": 1,
      "docs": [
        {
          "_id": "5ca897dd2efdc41b79d5fe96",
          "location_point": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
              -85.712883,
              37.09024
            ]
          },
          "__v": 0,
          "distance": 887.5656539981669
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
"Manually using $switch"
{
  "result": [
    {
      "_id": "greater than 500km",
      "count": 1,
      "docs": [
        {
          "_id": "5ca897dd2efdc41b79d5fe96",
          "location_point": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
              -85.712883,
              37.09024
            ]
          },
          "__v": 0,
          "distance": 887.5656539981669
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": "less than 5km",
      "count": 2,
      "docs": [
        {
          "_id": "5ca897dd2efdc41b79d5fe94",
          "location_point": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
              -95.712891,
              37.09024
            ]
          },
          "__v": 0,
          "distance": 0
        },
        {
          "_id": "5ca897dd2efdc41b79d5fe95",
          "location_point": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
              -95.712893,
              37.09024
            ]
          },
          "__v": 0,
          "distance": 0.00017759511720976155
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
"Legacy using $cond"
{
  "result": [
    {
      "_id": "greater than 500km",
      "count": 1,
      "docs": [
        {
          "_id": "5ca897dd2efdc41b79d5fe96",
          "location_point": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
              -85.712883,
              37.09024
            ]
          },
          "distance": 887.5656539981669
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": "less then 5km",
      "count": 2,
      "docs": [
        {
          "_id": "5ca897dd2efdc41b79d5fe94",
          "location_point": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
              -95.712891,
              37.09024
            ]
          },
          "distance": 0
        },
        {
          "_id": "5ca897dd2efdc41b79d5fe95",
          "location_point": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
              -95.712893,
              37.09024
            ]
          },
          "distance": 0.00017759511720976155
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This is a great answer! 